# MapKit not removing all annotations

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

MapKit seems to have a strange issue!!!

I have some code that adds some annotations and then I call

```
NSArray *existingpoints = mapView.annotations;
[mapView removeAnnotations:existingpoints];
                if ([mapView.annotations count] > 0) {
                    for(Plane *annotation in mapView.annotations){
                        NSLog(@"Name: %@",annotation.reg);
                        [mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
                    }
                    NSLog(@"\nMapCount:%i after attempting manual remove",[mapView.annotations count]);
                }
```

Now the strange bit is that from time to time I can get inside the mapView.annotations count being greater than 0.  So therefore I have extra "protection" and try and manually remove the item than gets NSLogged out.

However the the final count is still 1 after all that!

Most strange!

Comment: Not sure if this will cause this but do you have showsUserLocation turned on?

Comment: No, not in this example I don't.  I did and that was one of my first ports of call!

Comment: What happens when you examine the remaining annotation in the debugger? Look at the remaining object and its contents.

Comment: It is a valid object strangely enough and has all the properties. It even shows on the map and I can interact with it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have logged a bug with Apple....

They acknowledge this is an issue with 4.2

Comment: do you happen to know when it was fixed (i.e. from which iOS version) or whether it is still a bug?

Comment: To be honest I completely rewrote the code around it and it is fixed now